# how teamcity automatically building Pull Requests from GitHub？

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity Documentation states:

> In the version control settings of the config, make the branch specification:
>   +:refs/pull/*/merge

But in my VCS Root Card, there is no section named "Branch specification", what should i do ?

[Here is my current configuration screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeVUG.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to setup the `Branch specification` parameter, you need to click on "Show advanced options" at the bottom of the config screen (just above the save button)
Inside this textarea, you can set: `+:refs/pull/*/merge`